# Relating 2 tables (one-to-many) in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project with one SQL database and 2 related tables. One table for "EMPLOYEES" and their info (i.e. name, address, phone, etc..) and the other for appointment "VISITS" done by that "EMPLOYEE" (i.e. visit date, location, etc..).  The relation between these tables should of course be one (EMPLOYEE) to many (VISITS). That is, one "EMPLOYEE" can have many "VISITS" but every "VISIT" can only be attributed to one "EMPLOYEE". I have an "EMPLOYEE-ID" in the "EMPLOYEE" table which is the Primary Key and a "VISIT-ID" which is the Primary Key plus an "EMPLOYEE-ID" which is the Foreign Key in the "VISITS" table.

Now, the thing I can't figure out is how to dynamically start a new table column under the "VISITS" table from the "EMPLOYEE" table view so that the visit is attributed to the selected employee. In my mind there should be something like a drop-down menu with the employee's first & last name or the employee's ID# so that I can select the employee when entering a new "visit" in the "visits" table. Or a place in the "EMPLOYEE's" view where I can start a new "VISIT" in the "VISITS" table that will be attributed to only that employee.

I have not found a way to do this using Entity Framework. I can get Entity to open 2 views. One for each table and I can enter data in either table but the data in the "VISITS" table is not related to the "EMPLOYEE" table or at least it does not appear to be related in any way.

If more info about my project is needed just let me know exactly what is needed. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I come from a desktop development background.

IDE: Visual Studio for Web 2013 
Template: ASP.NET MVC 4 
Database: SQL Server Database 
.NET Framework: I must target .NET 4 
Language: C#

Comment: You say that you have no problem achieving this in a desktop application, which indicates that you want to do this in some other type of application.  The fact that you say "view" suggests that perhaps you want to create an ASP.NET MVC application, but nowhere in your question do you say that and there's no tag to indicate it either.  You have used the `tsql` tag though, which is irrelevant because you're not using any T-SQL anywhere.  Perhaps some clarification is in order, so review your question and your selection of tags.  Is `sql-server` relevant either, when it's abstracted away by EF?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I originally had all that information in there but it got edited out by someone else. Even the tags were changed. My original tags were: ASP.NET, C#, entity framework and MVC.

Comment: People, please, if you don't understand the question being asked don't go on editing out information that could help someone else answer the question. All the information about my project and the technologies in use were edited out of my question earlier. God knows how many people could have answered my question and did not because not enough info was left there. I have asked 2 questions in this site so far and both have been edited almost beyond recognition. Editing someone else's question is important but it is also a BIG responsibility.

Comment: I guess someone didn't really like my question. I got a -4 on the question alone and another -2. The question clearly shows that most of my project is done and I only need help with a small part of the project but that opinion was not shared by some in this community that opted to make their opinions anonymously.

Comment: I apologise for the fact that your question was butchered.  The fact that it was an MVC project is exactly what I was missing the whole way along and apparently you had that information there to begin with.  Unfortunately some people seem to think that they know far more than they really do about what makes a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question doesn't really have anything to do with EF.  EF is a data access technology so what you display in your views has nothing to do with EF.  In fact, a well-written application shouldn't be populating the view with EF objects anyway.  You should generally be mapping at least once and possibly twice, from EF to view model with possibly a separate DTO in between too.

Anyway, in your view, you would need get data from both tables via EF.  You would then populate a drop-down list (or the like) with the parent data and have the value of that populate that appropriate field of a child record.

Comment: Thanks for the answer jmcilhinney. I will try that and see how it goes. I think I was relying too much on EF as it has saved me from writing a lot of code in the past. I think this project is going to take a more hands on approach.